# Jquery datatable Invalid Argument exception - message - Trailing data on Laravel eloquent raw query

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, raw

I have setup Laravel Yajra datatable backend package to handle the work for the ajax query calls to view via a jquery datatable.  Everything worked great until I changed the eloquent query from:

```
static function for_table($farm_ids) 
    {
            return ChemProgramUser::select('chemprogramuser.id', 'chemprogramuser.farms_id as fid', 
            'chemprogramuser.description as head', 'chemprogramuser.hectares as ha', 
            'chemprogramapp.updated_at',
            'farms.name as fname', 'users.name', 'users.id as uid', 'chemprogramuser.type')
                ->leftJoin('farms', 'farms.id', '=', 'chemprogramuser.farms_id')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'chemprogramuser.manager_id')
                ->groupBy('chemprogramuser.id')
                ->orderBy('chemprogramuser.id', 'desc')
                ->where('chemprogramuser.program', '=', 1)
                ->whereIn('chemprogramuser.farms_id', $farm_ids)
                ->get();
```

to

```
static function for_table($farm_ids) 
    {
            return ChemProgramUser::select('chemprogramuser.id', 'chemprogramuser.farms_id as fid', 
            'chemprogramuser.description as head', 'chemprogramuser.hectares as ha', 
            DB::raw('GREATEST(chemprogramuser.updated_at, COALESCE(chemprogramapp.updated_at, \'1000-01-01\')) AS updated_at'), // this raw query caused the error
            'farms.name as fname', 'users.name', 'users.id as uid', 'chemprogramuser.type')
                ->leftJoin('farms', 'farms.id', '=', 'chemprogramuser.farms_id')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'chemprogramuser.manager_id')
                ->leftJoin('chemprogramapp', 'chemprogramapp.programuser_id', '=', 'chemprogramuser.id')
                ->groupBy('chemprogramuser.id')
                ->orderBy('chemprogramuser.id', 'desc')
                ->where('chemprogramuser.program', '=', 1)
                ->whereIn('chemprogramuser.farms_id', $farm_ids)
                ->get();
```

I am selecting the `GREATEST` date from two tables using the `DB` facade's `raw` method.  As soon I changed the query I received a jquery `InvalidArgumentException` with message `Trailing data`. But this is just on the production server, not on my localhost.

Can someone please give an idea why this error will occur?

Laravel version: 5.6.39

Answer (score 0):

So I found my answer, so I am posting it.  It seems it is the way I called the `DB::raw()` function on the query that caused the error.  The `raw()` function should incapsulate the complete `select` query string i.e.

```
select(
    DB::raw(
        ' chemprogramuser.id, chemprogramuser.farms_id as fid, ' .
        ' chemprogramuser.description as head, chemprogramuser.hectares as ha, ' .
        ' GREATEST(chemprogramuser.updated_at, COALESCE(chemprogramapp.updated_at, \'1000-01-01\')) AS updated_at, ' .
        ' farms.name as fname, users.name, users.id as uid, chemprogramuser.type '
        )
    )
```

The query then for some reason causes no error, even if the error is something obscure as `InvalidArgumentException` with message `Trailing data`.